# Display list in triggered send email based on supplied data

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, array, triggered-send

I have only recently started using the salesforce marketing cloud (exact target) to send out emails, so if there's something conceptually wrong with my question, forgive me :).

So let's say I have email - with some text - where I would like to display a list of items in a form of:

```
Dear %%Name%%. Your items are:
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Item one id </td>
      <td> Item one text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Item two id </td>
      <td> Item two text </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

This email is than sent out as a triggered send via api calls.

To populate this email with data I have created a Data Extension, where I defined a few fields, but I'm stuck on how to define the data for my list. So in this setup, what would be the best way of handling this situation?

I started looking into it and it seems like I can't simply create an array type in my data extension. So I was wondering if maybe I should pass my items in text - either as xml/json serialize -, that I can later on somehow loop through in the email to build up the list?

But I didn't really get anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to accomplish this with the API.

1. In your API call, include structured data in an attribute named `Whatever__HTML`.  The `__HTML` expands the max field length. This data will also be written to the Triggered Send [**Templated Data Extension**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_data_extension_from_a_template/) you created for your trigger.  The structured data payload can be XML or JSON.  In the email, you can parse the XML payload with the [**BuildRowsetFromXML()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/buildrowsetfromxml2/) AMPScript function and iterate through the result-set with a for-loop.  Same for a JSON payload except with the parsing and iterating is done with [**SSJS**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/server_side_javascript/) or [**GTL**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/guide_template_language/).  My recommendation would be to use AMPScript, because SSJS is slow and GTL is not documented very well.
2. Before firing your trigger API call, add the rows to a secondary Data Extension.  You can retrieve the data with an [**AMPScript lookup function**](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/) and iterate through it in the email.

**Update**

We generally work with XML payloads (option #1).  Here are a couple of screenshots of a Triggered Send Data Extension:

[image: DE columns]

[image: XML sample in DE]

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Is the naming of the attribute/field important for any reason? (I understand this is an example, just want to check if it gets validated at any point or not)

Comment: Generally no, but the `__HTML` suffix is a trick for storing > 4000 characters in a field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made it work with the XML. Just had some problem with parsing the data, but it's all sorted. Works well.