# How to upload XML data in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, xml, csv

I have a huge XML data and I wanted to import it as CSV file. How to upload XML data in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a tab-delimited file, instead of a comma-delimited. You can import XML, but you'll need to ensure that the XML blocks are all on one line (stripped of CR and LF).

Also, I mention a little SFMC trick for accommodating large field values in [**this post**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/146928/5202).  It's helpful when dealing with big blobs of XML.